# Refactor code - make class

Tags: c#, oop, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to make a class Photo where can I submit methods, because I will be use these methods many times in many pages.
So how can I send my image in parameter ?

Now I have :

```
PhotoChooserTask selectPhoto = null;
    private void chooseLogoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectPhoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
        selectPhoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectPhoto_Completed);
        selectPhoto.Show();
    }

    void selectPhoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

            //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            logoQrCodeImage.Source = bmp; 
        }
    }
```

And I made a class Photo:

```
public class Photo
{
    PhotoChooserTask selectPhoto = null;

    public void chooseLogo()
    {
        selectPhoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
        selectPhoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectPhoto_Completed);
        selectPhoto.Show();
    }

     void selectPhoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

            //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            logoQrCodeImage.Source = bmp; //ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking here. You should to to state more clearly your question

Comment: I guess @Frappeer references the line with //ERROR: `logoQrCodeImage.Source = bmp; //ERROR` as he doesn't have reference to logoQrCodeImage inside Photo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your class to support Tasks and then use an async/await event handler.  So your class would look like this:

```
public class PhotoChooser
{
    public Task<BitmapImage> ChoosePhoto()
    {
        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<BitmapImage>();
        var chooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
        chooser.Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.ChosenPhoto == null)
                {
                    taskSource.SetResult(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                    taskSource.SetResult(bmp);   
                }
            };
        chooser.Show();
        return taskSource.Task;
    }
}
```

The your event handler would look like this:

```
private async void ChoosePhoto_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var chooser = new PhotoChooser();
    logoQrCodeImage.Source = await chooser.ChoosePhoto();
}
```

**Update:**

If you are using Windows Phone 7 you can still use async and await by adding the Async for Silverlight, .NET 4, Windows Phone NuGet Package.  Just add a nuget reference and search for Async.  It should be the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a callback on what to do when the photo finishes selecting.

For example, you can add event to Photo class (you'd need to define class PhotoEventHandler too)

```
    public class PhotoEventArgs
    {
        public Bitmap Bmp;
    }

    public event EventHandler<PhotoEventArgs> photoSelectCompleted;
```

and in the method invoke the event

```
 void selectPhoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

        //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        if (photoSelectCompleted != null)
            photoSelectCompleted(this, new PhotoEventArgs(){ Bmp = bmp;});

    }
}
```

and in the original page subscribe to the event and in the eventhandler do this:

```
void photoSelectCompleted(object sender, PhotoEventArgs e)
{
logoQrCodeImage.Source = e.Bmp;
}
```